# Heatmap/density map by Canada's provinces in python?

Tags: python, gis

I'm trying to create a chart that is a map of Canada and for each provinces showing stronger colour for a higher the Percentage number and no colour when their is a NaN.

I'm new to shape files. How would I be able to do this in python?

My data:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11uDqXYJQ2_JAXTAO2zBl9ntMvwVczW_o/view?usp=sharing

I found a shape file here:
https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/5ab555c6e4b081f61ab78093

Example of something I'm trying to create in python:
[image]

Comment: Can you do it for other countries? Is there something specific about Canada that makes it more difficult?